# Visual Studio 2019 with vue.js formatting issue

Tags: javascript, c#, html, vue.js, visual-studio-2019

So I`m getting this issue with VS2019 when I try to format this section of code.

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="milestone.ascx.cs" Inherits="uc.dms.milestone" %>


<section class="content-header">
    <h1>Manage milestone

        <small>Lets manage some milestones</small>
    </h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#dashboard"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>Home</a></li>
        <li class="active">Manage Milestone</li>
    </ol>
</section>

<section class="content container-fluid">
    <div id="milestones">
              <div class="row" style="display:none;" id="updateselection">
            <div class="col-lg-12">

                   <div class="box box-info">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Select a study to update</h3>
            </div>
                       <div class="box-body">
                <select class="form-control" @change="updatethis($event.target)">
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                    <option v-for="i in updatestudies" :value="i.studypid">{{i.number}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
                        <div class="box-footer">
                            </div>
                       </div>
        </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</section>
<script>

</script>
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUrWK.png)

This error message line corresponds with , which has some vue.js code in it. This error occur when **ctrl + k + d** is pressed. This issue also appear when any vue.js code is "hit" in html, like the for-loop in option segment

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this the whole document? This is only 22 lines.

Comment: No, it consist out of 39 lines. but I get the problem at  "<select class="form-control" @change="updatethis($event.target)">' , which translate to line 25 in the document

Comment: Think it is something to do with the Code Formatter of visual studio 2019. But I`m not sure

Comment: Can you post the full document? There's nothing wrong with the markup - so I expect something is wrong somewhere else in the document.

Comment: I have updated the code section. If I comment the vue.js parts out of the HTML the code formatter works perfectly

Comment: Hm, yeah I see nothing wrong with this. I'd recommend removing parts of the line one-at-a-time to see if you can narrow it down. Does removing the line entirely allow it to format?

Comment: Yeah, so if I do this:

' <%-- <select class="form-control" @change="updatethis($event.target)">
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                    <option v-for="i in updatestudies" :value="i.studypid">{{i.number}}</option>--%>'

Visual Studio 2019 code formatter works perfectly fine. Which absolutely blows my mind. 

The code works

Answer (score 0):

I think you get this error due to the parameters here:

```
@change="updatethis($event.target)"
```

If updatethis is a function inside your methods block of your component, just write

```
<select class="form-control" @change="updatethis">
```

And the method :

```
methods: {
  updatethis(myArgument){
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error (As mentioned in the picture above) when try to format ( ctrl + k + d) in visual studio 2019.

Comment: Think it is something to do with the Code Formatter of visual studio 2019. But I`m not sure